# Wrapper for vector::insert function

Tags: c++, vector, insert, iterator

I'm doing a little wrapper for `std::vector` class. I don't use templates: my vector declared as `std::vector<int>`.  Now I need a wrapper for `insert` function, but I don't know which types do parameters have. I've tried this:

```
std::vector<int>::iterator insert(std::vector<int>::const_iterator position, std::vector<int>::iterator first, std::vector<int>::iterator last) {
    prepare_to_changing();
    data_->vector_.insert(position, first, last);
}
```

This is how I invoke this function:

```
insert(this->nums_.end(), tmp.nums_.begin() + this->nums_.size(), tmp.nums_.end());
```

where `nums_` is `std::vector<int>`

but the compiler says `first`, `last` and return types doesn't correct. Which should I use?

Comment: you should show how do you invoke the function insert and this function definition, function declaration is fine.

Answer (score 1):

```
  template <class InputIterator>
        void insert (iterator position, InputIterator first, InputIterator last);
```

So change your return type of insert function as void because you are not returning anything:

```
void insert(std::vector<int>::iterator position, std::vector<int>::iterator first, std::vector<int>::iterator last) {
    prepare_to_changing();
    data_->vector_.insert(position, first, last);
}
```

Comment: But `this` and `tmp` is different objects, so it doesn't mean `nums_.end()`, actually I don't get which `nums_` are you talking about?

Comment: Now it says `error: no viable conversion from '__wrap_iter<const_pointer>' to '__wrap_iter<pointer>'`

Answer (score 1):

Insert is as:

```
template <class InputIterator>
void insert (iterator position, InputIterator first, InputIterator last);
```

Test program:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Vector
{
private:
    vector<int> vec;
public:
    void insert(vector<int>::const_iterator position, vector<int>::iterator first, vector<int>::iterator last)
    {
        vec.insert(position, first, last);
    }
    void print()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++)
            cout << vec.at(i) << " ";
        cout << endl;
    }
    vector<int>::const_iterator begin()
    {
        return vec.begin();
    }
    vector<int>::const_iterator end()
    {
        return vec.end();
    }
};
int main()
{
    Vector obj;
    vector<int> vec;
    vec.push_back(1);
    vec.push_back(2);

    obj.insert(obj.begin(), vec.begin(), vec.end());
    obj.print();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Compiler says error: `no matching member function for call to 'insert'` in 12 line. Also it says `note: candidate function [with _InputIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int *, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >] not viable: no known conversion from '__normal_iterator<const_pointer, [...]>' to '__normal_iterator<pointer, [...]>' for 1st argument `.

Comment: runs fine for me (VC++). I notice this does not work with gcc. From the error i receive, i dont see any signature for vector::insert as i defined above. Seems to me this version is not implemented.